# Symfony sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList validation

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Is there any validation for `sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList` and I am having problem when the form is not valid [!isValid()] and reload the page with previous data. The choices don't show the previously selected value and I am not getting any value even if I select some value from choice for the next time.

My form is like this

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
            'event_title' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'client_list' => new sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList(array(
                'choices' => $client,
                'associated_first' => false,
                'label_associated' => '',
                'label_unassociated' => ''
            )),
));

$this->setValidators(array(
            'event_title' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),  
           ));
```

//and in my controller

```
if($form1->isValid()){

               $resource->title = $frmField['event_title'];
               $resource->save();
               //var_dump($frmField);
               return $this->renderPartial('newEvent', array('form1' => $form1));
            } else {
                var_dump($frmField);
                return $this->renderPartial('createEvent', array('form1' => $form1));
            }
```

couldn't set the validator as I don't know it. And have completely no idea why isn't it getting any value while submitting it for 2nd time and onwards

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a validation problem. The selected values are never submitted. I guess that, even if the form is valid, the values are not saved (you can check that on the database).
The problem is (I guess) that the "selected values" select are populated with values, but this values are never selected. Every option in that select should not only exists, even be "selected". The plugin is missing that part. I solved horrifyingly selecting every option when the form is submitted (by jquery).
Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_html_id').submit(function(e) {
         // You should find this html id for the "selected values" select
         $('#your_entity_client_list option').attr('selected','selected');
         return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope this workaround could help you.
Sorry for my bad english.